# Altering a single record in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to select from one temp table into another. Every record will be copied over as is, unless the ID = 17. In this case I want the ID to be 18 in the second table. How would I do this?

Comment: It seems strange to do it, but you could do a `Case when ID = 17 Then 18 Else ID End` in your `Select` statement.

Comment: Are you creating a new temporary table, or inserting into an existing one?

Comment: do both temp tables already exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both tables already exists, use this query:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #t2 ON -- only needed if ID is a Primary Key

INSERT INTO #t2 (
    ID
    ,Column1
    ,Column2
    )
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN #t1.ID = 17 THEN 18
        ELSE #t1.ID
    END AS ID
    ,#t1.Column1
    ,#t1.Column2
FROM #t1

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #t2 OFF -- only needed if ID is a Primary Key
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  ,CASE WHEN ID=17 THEN 18
        ELSE ID
   END ID
INTO #temp2
FROM #temp1
```

Comment: If the structure of the tables are the same, this would result in an error.  This would add an extra field at the end.

Comment: Yes, I agree, because the ID column would get duplicated. However, Iam not familiar with the table' structure and thats why I have used star.